# Include and Static statements are not being recognized with GitPages

Tags: html, css, django, github, github-pages

I am new to GitPages and have successfully built and ran my page. However, the {% include %} and {% static %} methods in my index.html aren't being registered. As you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7oHA.png). Additionally, my two static files referenced in this file (circleselfie.png and home.css) have weird [characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkMKJ.png) in their static paths when inspecting the page. Here is my project: https://github.com/jishli113/JSite/tree/master. What is causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gitpages, unfortunately, doesn't support a django backend. It's primarily for static/clientside sites, so your templates are just being treated as normal HTML.